# Does agora support ringtone on video call

Tags: agora.io

i want to know does agora.io support video call ringing option on client phone like person A is calling to person B and person B phone rings on incoming call. i am working in android using agora.io SDK

Answer (score 1):

Agora supports this functionality using ConnectionService and the Agora Real-Time Messaging SDK.

Android: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling/tree/master/OpenDuo-Android

iOS: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling/tree/master/OpenDuo-iOS

...

To give yourself a better understanding of the Android API, I would recommend that you look into [Android's ConnectService API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService) for leveraging Android's UI for "calls" and "ringing". Android's Developer Documentation has an [example of how to build a "Calling App"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged).

Comment: for android tutorial link, it will show this error https://prnt.sc/sqm20e , as `libs/agora-rtm-sdk.jar` does not exist.

Comment: did you add in the libraries? the demos don't normally contain the sdk itself.

Comment: Yes, I did @Hermes , but that error is still persist.